# Invitation links sent via emails getting auto clicked by email client's link preview feature. Any way to stop this?

Tags: php, email, email-client

So an app I am building allows people to send invitations to other people. The invitation is an email with a special link, containing a unique token, that will "accept" the invitation when clicked.

During testing I found that simply viewing the email in hotmail was triggering the invitation to be accepted, due to its link preview feature I believe. As soon as the email is opened, the email client requests the link in the email's body in some way, the server sees the token in the request URL and accepts the invite, all without the invitee clicking anything.

I've tried detecting if a request is a 'HEAD' request using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`, but that doesn't seem to be working. It seems to be coming through as a GET request, perhaps because of the GET parameter in the URL.

Has anyone come across this before? Is there a way to stop this from happening, or way to design the email that will stop this? Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I've come across this issue before - it seems some antispam solutions also do this. Often it's best to direct them to a "confirmation" page in which they have to click a button/follow a prompt. After they've done that you would then delete the token.

Comment: You can implement user agent checks and even JavaScript can be used but neither one can be super reliable. In these cases there's not an entirely accurate way to know if a user opened the link or if it was opened automatically.

Comment: The solution I implemented still used a query parameter (`$_GET` variable) that populated a hidden form field. The user would then click "Confirm" which would submit that form - finalising the request.

Comment: @Rylee thanks. I ended up going with your suggestion and linking them to a stand alone form where they have to click to accept the invite. Seems to work great.

Answer (score 0):

If those antispam engines don't include javascript engine (?) you could confirm the token on the event of `load` of the page using javascript. If javascript is not available then you can present a "confirm" button with a link.

first-level.html

```html
<script>
function do_confirm() {
  var token = get_qs("token");  // TODO: get_qs gets querystring param
  var url = "second-level.php?token=" + token
  var my_awesome_script = document.createElement('script');
  my_awesome_script.setAttribute('src', url);
  document.head.appendChild(my_awesome_script);
}
</script>
<body onload="do_confirm()">
  hang on or click here...
</body>
```

second-level.php

```php
<?php
// do something with $token from $_REQUEST["token"]
?>
<body>
  thank you for confirming
</body>
```

This is just a sketch that can be elaborated. First I would check if indeed the assumption of no javascript is true.